# claims-based web application by using Windows PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, powershell, 2016, web-application

I followed https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee806885.aspx to Create a claims-based web application by using Windows PowerShell.

it created successfully but enables Form based authentication and anonymous authentication.

How create a new web application without enable Form based authentication and anonymous authentication?

EDIT:

[image]

[image]

EDIT

IIS warning

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
$authprov = New-SPAuthenticationProvider -UseWindowsIntegratedAuthentication -DisableKerberos

New-SPWebApplication -Name "name of the web" -Port "port number" -Path "Path of IIS site" -AuthenticationMethod NTLM -AuthenticationProvider $authprov -Url "Url of the Web application" -ApplicationPool "App Pool Name" -ApplicationPoolAccount (Get-SPManagedAccount "Domain\user") -DatabaseServer "DB Server name" -DatabaseName "DB anme"
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I got WARNING: The Windows Classic authentication method is deprecated in this
release and the default behavior of this cmdlet, which creates Windows Cl
based web application, is obsolete. It is recommended to use Claims
authentication methods. You can create a web application that uses Claims
authentication method by specifying the AuthenticationProvider parameter
 this cmdlet.

Comment: Refer to the http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234549
for more information. Please note that the default behavior of this cmdle
expected to change in the future release to create a Claims authenticatio
based web application instead of a Windows Classic based web application.

Comment: yes, ignore it and let it finish...see if it create a Web application as per ur requirement

Comment: ok sir, i got the same warning in the past. the warning run away when i removed -AuthenticationMethod NTLM , why i need AuthenticationMethod NTLM

Comment: as i said ignore the warning, as it is bug in the command....what you trying to do....a claims based web application with windows authentication(ntlm)...so dont remove that one unless u want different authentication....as i said earlier...let it complete with that warning and then check ur web application

Comment: new error ApplicationPoolAccount is not found.

Comment: is account in the managed account list?

Comment: i added -ApplicationPoolAccount please update your answer

Comment: Check updated command, i miss the app pool account name

Comment: ok, why i need (Get-SPManagedAccount "Domain\user") ? i added -ApplicationPoolAccount "domain\usename" directly !

Comment: sir , please check the quest update

Comment: dont change the IIS settings, these are required in order to SharePoint work....like Anonymous access and Form base....it will not configure it.....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58577/discussion-between-waqas-sarwar-mvp-and-aashirya).

Answer (score 0):

Create a classic-mode web application by using PowerShell

Use the procedure in this section to create a new classic-mode SharePoint Server web application using PowerShell.
To create a classic-mode web application by using PowerShell
Verify that you have the following memberships:
securityadmin fixed server role on the SQL Server instance.
db_owner fixed database role on all databases that are to be updated.
Administrators group on the server on which you are running PowerShell cmdlets.
You must read about_Execution_Policies.
From the PowerShell command prompt, type the following:

New-SPWebApplication -Name  
-ApplicationPool 
-AuthenticationMethod 
-ApplicationPoolAccount 
-Port  -URL

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/security-for-sharepoint-server/create-claims-based-web-applications